# R: processing and converting emoji into a canonical form

Tags: r, unicode, character-encoding, emoji

As of one week ago I was a sweet summer child data scientist who knew nothing of character encodings.

I am trying to capture emoji in text (sources pulled from various places) and tokenize each emoji into a single canonical form that I can then do my analyses on.

The same emoji can appear in multiple forms.

For instance (and this is solely encodings I have found in my data):

```
\U01F9E8
<U+1F9E8>
&#129512;
<f0><9f><a7><a8>
```

all refer [to the same emoji.](https://emojis.wiki/firecracker/)

So far, I have been unable to find any R function, package or otherwise, that will let me freely interconvert between these encodings.

utf8ToInt() can handle some but not others:

```
> utf8ToInt("U+1F9E8")
[1] 85 43 49 70 57 69 56

> utf8ToInt("\U+1F9E8")
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\U"

> utf8ToInt("\\U+1F9E8")
[1] 92 85 43 49 70 57 69 56

> utf8ToInt("U01F9E8")
[1] 85 48 49 70 57 69 56

> utf8ToInt("\\U01F9E8")
[1] 92 85 48 49 70 57 69 56

> utf8ToInt("\U01F9E8")
[1] 129512
```

Only the last input gives the correct answer. In theory one could use regular expressions to convert these similar examples into the final one, but the presence of the escape character '\' has really put roadblacks in my attempts to do so.

I have been stuck on this for the last few days and it's been really affecting my productivity. **Is there a trick, a function or a package I can use in R that would help me interconvert the codes for these emojis?**

Answer (score 0):

Simple text filter for normalising:

```
› cat 56283978.txt
lorem \U01F9E8 ipsum
lorem <U+1F9E8> ipsum
lorem &#129512; ipsum
lorem <f0><9f><a7><a8> ipsum

› perl -MEncode=decode_utf8 -0777 -lpe'

    s   { < U \+ ( [[:xdigit:]]+ ) > }
        { "\\U" . substr("000000" . $1, -6) }egmsx;

    s   { & \# ( [[:digit:]]+ ) ; }
        { sprintf("\\U%06X", $1) }egmsx;

    s   { ( (?: < [[:xdigit:]]{2} > )+ ) }
        {   sprintf "\\U%06X", ord decode_utf8 join "",
            map chr hex, grep length, split /[<>]/, $1 }egmsx;

' 56283978.txt
lorem \U01F9E8 ipsum
lorem \U01F9E8 ipsum
lorem \U01F9E8 ipsum
lorem \U01F9E8 ipsum
```

There are more straight-forward solutions with [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack), but afaik that is not implemented in R, and I wanted to keep the regex portable for you.